# get_footer(); and Google maps conflicts

Tags: javascript, wordpress

My website doesn't display Google maps. The Console says that I include the API multiple times and I didn't. 
After that I decided to delete all the javascript and use a Google Maps plugin, and I still having the same error.

I suspect that it has to be calling the get_footer(); function because if I delete `>?` from my footer.php, the map shows up but I lose the video on the header and the animation that I created for my nav.

Here's the code of my footer.php

```
        </footer>

       <!-- Map -->


        <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Bx Slider JS -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Add JS counter lib -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Add wow js lib -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Custom Js -->
        <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<?php wp_footer(); >?
</body>
</html>
```

and page-home.php

```
    </section>
        <aside class="clients">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <a href="https://shucksfishhouse.com" target="_blank">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/shucks.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <a href="https://www.absolutelyfresh.com/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/abs.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <a href="https://baileysbreakfast.com/" target="_blank">
                            <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/assets/images/baileys.jpg" class="img-responsive img-centered" alt="">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>    
<?php get_footer();
```

Here is the website: http://dundeedell.com/

Comment: Add the closing PHP tag back to your `get_footer()` line. You are including the maps API twice. Once in the header and once in the footer. The one in the footer I'm assuming is being added by the eventON plugin

Comment: that's what I had the very 1st time. That makes the site works perfectly except for the map

Comment: I just disabled de API from eventON. Thanks "Jrod"

Comment: It seems like the PHP closing tag in your footer.php has wrong syntax. It should be ?> instead of >?